# React JSX Unable to access variable inside div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm currently rendering a list which I've defined in the render method, like so

```
        render() {
            var listDisplay = items.map((item, i) => {
                ....
            }

            return (
                <TabPanel>
                    <Scrollbars>
                        {listDisplay}
                    </Scrollbars>
                </TabPanel>
            )
        }
```

This works as intended and the listDisplay shows up correctly. However, when I surround the Scrollbars with `<div>`, nothing shows up.

I feel like I might be missing something obvious, but right now I have no clue what's going on. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you inspected the generated DOM? It may be a layout issue. Without knowing how `TabPanel` and `Scrollbars` work or what `listDisplay` contains it's impossible to help. Adding `<div>` will certainly not make `listDisplay` inaccessibly suddenly. This is still normal JavaScript which has lexical scoping. Maybe `TabPanel` cannot work with a `<div>` as child.

Comment: provide complete render() code. as of things looks fine.

Comment: The full render() code is very long so I had to shorten it. `listDisplay` contains: `var listDisplay =  list_items.map((item, i) => {
            return (
                <li>
                    <span
                        className="test_exam_item"
                        style={{color: '#3066BE', cursor: 'pointer'}}
                        onClick={() => this.submit_item("Item name: "+item[1], item[0])}
                    >
                      {test[0]}
                    </span>
                </li>
            )
        });`
This has no issues without the <div> tags

Comment: Scrollbars is imported from the library 'react-custom-scrollbars' (https://github.com/malte-wessel/react-custom-scrollbars), and TabPanel is imported from 'react-tabs' (https://github.com/reactjs/react-tabs)

I'm just very curious as to why it won't work with <div> but works perfectly without...

Comment: Update: I inspected the source code and looks like all the items are being generated, but just not being displayed properly for some reason. Will investigate and give an update on the issue

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments above suggested, it was a layout issue rather than being unable to access the variable. In this case, using `<div>` tags around the Scrollbar component alters the layout. Getting rid of it fixed the problem.